# Could it be argued that Ada subtypes are equivalent to dependent types?

Tags: types, ada, dependent-type, type-theory

I've been trying to wrap my head around Ada, and I've been reading a bit about [dependent types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type) in Agda and Idris.

Could it be argued that [subtypes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Type_System#Subtype_categories) in Ada are equivalent to dependent types?

Comment: See [*§3.2 Types and Subtypes: Notes*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-2.html#p10) for more.

Comment: Not if 'a dependent type is a type whose definition depends on a value', as per the first sentence of your citation. A base type is not a value.

Answer (score 3):

> In computer science and logic, a dependent type is a type whose definition depends on a value. A "pair of integers" is a type. A "pair of integers where the second is greater than the first" is a dependent type because of the dependence on the value.

So then you can use subtypes to implement them--

```
-- The "pair of integers" from the example.
Type Pair is record
  A, B : Integer;
end record;

-- The "where the second is greater than the first" constraint.
Subtype Constrained_Pair is Pair
  with Dynamic_Predicate => Constrained_Pair.B > Constrained_Pair.A;
```

Comment: But you could have put that predicate directly on `Pair`.

Comment: @JacobSparreAndersen -- I implemented the quoted portion: *A "pair of integers" is a type.* and *A "pair of integers where the second is greater than the first" is a dependent type because of the dependence on the value.*

Comment: @JacobSparreAndersen -- (Also the `type` keyword is the "*first subtype indication*", according to the LRM.)

Answer (score 1):

No, not as I read the formal definition of dependent types you referenced.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example:

```
type A_T is range 1 .. 50;
subtype B_T is A_T;
```

Sub_type `B_T` is in fact the "same" as the type `A_T`, since it does not pose any restrictions on it. It is rather a renaming of type `A_T` for convenience, for example. Thus, you cannot say that Ada sub-types are dependent types.